# nLab's proof that right adjoints are unique up to natural isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to understand [nLab's proof that right adjoints are unique up to natural isomorphism](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/adjoint+functor#basic_properties). Let $L\colon C\to D$ be a functor, and $R_1$ and $R_2$ two right adjoints, i.e., we have natural bijections
$$\hom(-, R_1(-))\cong \hom(L(-), -)$$
and
$$\hom(-, R_2(-))\cong\hom(L(-), -),$$
and hence in particular a natural isomorphism
$$\Phi_d\colon \hom(-, R_1(d))\cong \hom(-, R_2(d))$$
for each $d\in D$. By Yoneda there is an isomorphism
$$\phi_d\colon R_1(d)\to R_2(d)$$
for each $d\in D$. Then nLab says:

> But then the uniqueness statement of Prop. 1.5 implies that the collection of these isomorphisms for each object constitues a natural isomorphism between the functors.

The "uniqueness statement of Prop. 1.5" states that if $R\colon\mathrm{Ob}(D)\to\mathrm{Ob}(C)$ is a class function such that for all $d\in D$,
$$\Psi_d\colon \hom(L(-), d)\cong\hom(-, R(d))$$
is a natural isomorphism, there is a unique way to extend $R$ to a functor $D\to C$ such that $\Psi_d$ is natural in $d$.

Why does this imply that
$$\phi_d\colon R_1(d)\to R_2(d)$$
is natural in $d$ (i.e., that $R_1$ is naturally isomorphic to $R_2$)?

Comment: I believe what is meant on the nlab is as follows. You can transport the functoriality of $R_1$ (the way it acts on morphisms) to $R_2$ in a unique way along the isomorphisms $_d$ such that $_d$ becomes a natural isomorphism. (You forget the way $R_2$ acts on morphisms and you get a new functor.) It gives another functoriality for $R_2$ such that it is left adjoint to $L$ with the prescribed isomorphisms $\operatorname{Hom}(x,R_2(y)) ≅ \operatorname{Hom}(L(x),y)$.[...]

Comment: But the uniqueness of proposition 1.5 says that there is a unique functoriality for $R_2$ making this happen, so you actually end up with the original way $R_2$ acts on morphisms.

Comment: That being said, I think this is not a very easy way of understanding what is going on. It is easier to think like this: you know that $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(x,R_2(y)) ≅ \Hom(x,R_1(y))$. This is an isomorphism between two functors $\newcommand{\op}{\mathrm{op}}C → [D^{\op},\mathbf{Set}]$. Let $y : D ↣ [D^{\op},\mathbf{Set}]$ be the Yoneda embedding. The two functors are $y∘R_1$ and $y∘R_2$, so since $y$ is a fully faithful embedding, this means that $R_1 ≅ R_2$.

Comment: @Idéophage Thanks!

Comment: @Idéophage Here's a problem though: As you say there is a unique way to modify $R_2$ on morphisms (call the modification $R_2'$) such that $\{\phi_d\}_d$ is natural in $d$. Now we want to show that in fact $R_2=R_2'$. (Then we are done.) To prove that we apply the "uniqueness statement of Prop. 1.5". That is, we need to show that the natural isomorphisms $\hom(L-, -)\to\hom(-, R_2-)$ and $\hom(L-, -)\to\hom(-, R_2'-)$ are the same. But this is not clear at all. Since $\hom(L-, -)\to\hom(-, R_2-)$ can be *any* natural isomorphism, whereas

Comment: $\hom(L-, -)\to\hom(-, R_2'-)$ comes from the natural isomorphism $\hom(L-, -)\to\hom(-, R_1(-))$ (by transporting it using $\phi_d$ to $R_2'$).

Comment: In the notation above, $\Psi_d$ is fixed. You cannot use $\Psi_d$ for $R_2$ and a different $\Psi_d'$ for $R_2'$ and then conclude that $R_2=R_2'$. You have to use one and the same function $\Psi_d$.

Comment: (Your "easier way of thinking" is cheating: you need to prove that if $y$ is fully faithful and $y\circ R_1\cong y\circ R_2$, then $R_1\cong R_2$. I guess to prove that you'd have to repeat the above argument. But this is just a side remark, I'm more interested how to fix the above problem.)

Comment: Yes, the isomorphism $\hom(Lx,y) → \hom(x,R_2'y)$ is obtained by taking $\hom(Lx,y) ≅ \hom(x,R_1y)$ and then post-composing by $φ_y$. So is the isomorphism $\hom(Lx,y) → \hom(x,R_2y)$: we compose $\hom(Lx,y) → \hom(x,R_1y)$ and $\hom(x,R_1y) → \hom(x,R_2y)$ since it's how the latter isomorphism is defined. But it is also post-composition by $φ_y$ by definition of $φ_y$. Do you agree with that?

Comment: @Idéophage Yup, now I agree. Thank you very much for unconfusing me. :) Is my sentence starting with "The "uniqueness statement of Prop. 1.5" states [...]" completely correct? I ask because literally, what the uniqueness part of Prop. 1.5 says is "In this case there is a unique way to extend R from a function on objects to a function on morphisms such as to make it a functor R:D→C which is right adjoint to L" --- but this is clearly false. I think one has to modify it to "such as to make it a functor R:D→C such that $\Psi_d$ is natural in $d$", right?

Comment: Also, don't you agree that for proving $y\circ R_1\cong y\circ R_2\land\text{$y$ fully faithful}\implies R_1\cong R_2$ one needs to give essentially the same argument?

Comment: Hi! Yes, your sentence is correct, there is a unique way of extending $R$ on morphisms such that $L$ is left adjoint to $R$ *with the hom-isomorphisms being the $Ψ_d$*.

Comment: I don't know if I agree that it's "the same argument". I believe there should be more or less only one way to do it anyway because there is not much involved in the situation. But I find the organization of the nlab not straightforward at all. Essentially, what they do is the following. We have a fully faithful embedding $\newcommand{\c}{\mathbf}y : \c X→\c Y$ and two functors $F,G : \c A → \c X$ such that $Fy ≅ Gy$.

Comment: In order to prove that $F≅G$, they say that we have an isomorphism pointwise because $y$ is full. And instead of directly saying that it's then a natural isomorphism because $y$ is faithful, they *redefine* the functor $G$ on morphisms and appeal to some other property that they happen to have proven earlier (this part wouldn't even work if $y$ was not faithful)... anyway, it's a bit complicated for what it is in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are helping me a lot. :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!